# How do i post data via ajax in django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a dynamically updating form and when its submitted, i'm trying to post the data to a views function and get the response back. Here's my template file:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var msg = '';
    for(var i=1; i<counter; i++){
        msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
    }

   $.post("/results/", {'data', msg},function(res) {
   console.log("Got a result", res);

  });
});
```

The form part:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="POST" action="">{%  csrf_token %}
          <div class="modal-body">

            <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
                <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
                    <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='text' id='textbox1' class="form-control" placeholder="Body Text">
                </div>
            </div><br/>

            <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton' class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton' class="btn btn-primary">

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id='getButtonValue' value="Save Changes">

          </div>
        </form>
```

The urls.py file:

```
(r'^results/$', views.results),
```

And here is the view function:

```
def results(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == POST:
        name = request.POST['name']
        #add the post data to database.
        return HttpResponse("Thanks! Successfully updated!")
    else:
        sys.exit(1) # print some error message
```

I'm getting a 403 forbidden error. I have used ajax before but i never encountered this error.

Comment: Django form post requires CSRF token. For your example to work, you need @csrf_exempt applied at views function.

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't use `event` implicitely: `$("#myForm").submit(function(event){...});`

Comment: I updated the form part if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [explains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) how to use cross-site request forgery protection in Ajax.

Comment: is it just really a csrf token issue? Is there something wrong with my views function?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Django validates POST requests by using something called a CSRF token to to prevent cross site scripting attacks.

In order to get your script to work, you'll need to pass the CSRF token as a parameter by retrieving it from the user's cookies or using the following code in your form view

```
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

You can find more instructions and details at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it

Alternatively, you place @csrf_exempt decorator on the line above `def results(request):` to disable csrf for that particular view.